# Which addresses to change in Cassandra.yaml for this situation?

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-14.04, datastax, kvm

I created a virtual machine on a Ubuntu 14.04 server (IP address - a.b.c.d) using KVM. I installed Cassandra on this virtual machine (with IP address 192.x.y.z).

How can I send write requests or stress requests from another Ubuntu server machine ( IP address - p.q.r.s ) to the Cassandra on the Virtual machine?

EDIT
I have forwarded the ports 7000,9042 on the host to the same ports of the virtual machine using iptables.
When I mention the IP address of the host in listen_address
listen_address = IP of host (a.b.c.d)
rpc_address = 192.x.y.z

It says Unable to bind to address /a.b.c.d . Set listen_address in cassandra.yaml to an interface you can bind to, e.g., your private IP address on EC2

Answer (score 1):

In `cassandra.yaml`, please change

- rpc_address
- listen_address

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey @chaitan64arun. Please refer to the latest edits. I have already tried changing the addresses. Thank you